# When back button is pressed and navigation drawer is open, my app closes instead of closing drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement material design to my app and is following a tutorial. The problem I have is when the navigation drawer is open, and I click on the "back" button on the phone, it closes my app instead of closing the drawer. How do I close the drawer instead of exit the app? Thanks.

Here's the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
       // getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
}
```

Here is layout xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
     android:name="test.materialdesign.com.materialdesign.activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to close the navigation drawer on back press?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Currently, it just exit the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To close drawer, when back button is pressed, you have to override `onBackPressed()`, this way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement onBackpress() And try this example

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 1) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to override the member function `onBackPressed`;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
  } else {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```